# Oracle SQL/PLSQL: change type of specific columns in one time

Tags: sql, oracle

Assume following table named t1:

```
create table t1(
    clid number,
    A number,
    B number,
    C number
)

insert into t1 values(1, 1, 1, 1);
insert into t1 values(2, 0, 1, 0);
insert into t1 values(3, 1, 0, 1);

clid   A   B   C  
1      1   1   1
2      0   1   0
3      1   0   1
```

Type of columns A, B, and C is number. What I need to do is to change types of those columns to VARCHAR but in a quite tricky way.
In my real table I need to change datatype for hundred of columns so it is not so convenient to write a statement like following hundred of time:

```
ALTER TABLE table_name
MODIFY column_name datatype;
```

What i need to do is rather to convert all columns to VARCHAR except CLID column like we can do that in Python or R
Is there any way to do so in Oracle SQL or PLSQL?

Appreciate your help.

Comment: an idea, create a tmp table `create table t1(
    clid number,
    A  varchar(10),
    B  varchar(10),
    C varchar(10)
)`. And then insert into tmp select * from t1; and then replace t1 using tmp.

Comment: Trying to alter the datatype will probably fail with `ORA-01439: column to be modified must be empty to change datatype`.

Comment: As others have shown, this is not as easy as you'd like.  That said, I would _seriously_ question the supposed requirement.  Why in the world would you want to store a NUMBER or a DATE as a varchar?  Therein lies madness.  "Abandon all hope you who enter herein".  There is a _sound reason_ why all rdbms systems implement data types other than 'character'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a example of procedure that can help...
It accepts two parameters that should be a name of your table and list of columns you do not want to change...
At the begining there is a cursor that gets all the column names for your table except the one that you do not want to change...

Then it loop's though the columns and changes them...

```
CREATE OR REPLACE procedure test_proc(p_tab_name in varchar2
                                      , p_col_names in varchar2)

IS

v_string varchar2(4000);

cursor c_tab_cols 
is
SELECT column_name
FROM ALL_TAB_COLS 
WHERE table_name = upper(p_tab_name)
and column_name not in (select regexp_substr(p_col_names,'[^,]+', 1, level) from dual
                        connect by regexp_substr(p_col_names, '[^,]+', 1, level) is not null);
 
begin
 FOR i_record IN c_tab_cols 
    loop
       v_string := 'alter table ' || p_tab_name || ' modify ' 
       || i_record.column_name || ' varchar(30)';
       EXECUTE IMMEDIATE v_string; 
    end loop;
end;
/
```

Here is a demo:

> [DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=e69479f1a7df67e35244fb1ae6a8bfba)

You can also extend this procedure with a type of data you want to change into... and with some more options I am sure....

Comment: Unfortunately, that won't work if those columns aren't empty (and they aren't, according to what the OP posted in the question). But - as they accepted the answer, I guess they are happy with it (and so am I).

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, that isn't as simple as you'd want it to be. It is not a problem to *write query which will write query for you* (by querying `USER_TAB_COLUMNS`), but - column must be empty in order to change its datatype:

```
SQL> create table t1 (a number);

Table created.

SQL> insert into t1 values (1);

1 row created.

SQL> alter table t1 modify a varchar2(1);
alter table t1 modify a varchar2(1)
                      *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01439: column to be modified must be empty to change datatype


SQL>
```

If there are hundreds of columns involved, maybe you can't even

- create additional columns in the same table (of `VARCHAR2` datatype)
- move values in there
- drop "original" columns
- rename "new" columns to "old names"

because there'a limit of 1000 columns per table.

Therefore,

- creating a new table (with appropriate columns' datatypes),
- moving data over there,
- dropping the "original" table
- renaming the "new" table to "old name"

is probably what you'll finally do. Note that it won't be necessarily easy either, especially if there are foreign keys involved.

---

A "query that writes query for you" might look like this (Scott's sample tables):

```
SQL> SELECT    'insert into dept (deptno, dname, loc) '
  2         || 'select '
  3         || LISTAGG ('to_char(' || column_name || ')', ', ')
  4               WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY column_name)
  5         || ' from emp'
  6    FROM user_tab_columns
  7   WHERE     table_name = 'EMP'
  8         AND COLUMN_ID <= 3
  9  /

insert into dept (deptno, dname, loc) select to_char(EMPNO), to_char(ENAME), to_char(JOB) from emp

SQL>
```

It'll save you from typing names of *hundreds of columns*.

Answer (score 0):

I think its not possible to change data type of a column if values are there...
Empty the column by copying values to a dummy column and change data types.